# VS Express 2012 C++ lambda Intellisense error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I've got a short snippet of code involving a lambda that compiles fine, but Intellisense throws an error.

```
items.erase(remove_if(begin(items), end(items),
[](const Item& mItem){ return mItem.booleanMember; }),
end(items));
```

The error is

```
IntelliSense: more than one conversion function from "lambda []bool (const Item &mItem)->bool" to "<error-type>" applies:
        function "lambda []bool (const Item &mItem)->bool::operator bool (*)(const Item &mItem)() const"
        function "lambda []bool (const Item &mItem)->bool::operator bool (*)(const Item &mItem)() const"
        function "lambda []bool (const Item &mItem)->bool::operator bool (*)(const Item &mItem)() const"
```

If I change the code to

```
items.erase(remove_if(begin(items), end(items),
[&](const Item& mItem)->bool{ return mItem.booleanMember; }),
end(items));
```

Then the error goes away. I'd be fine with that, but I don't exactly know what's happening. I know I am not explicitly specifying a bool return value (and with this changed code, I am), but I thought that I didn't need to if there was only one line in the lambda. Also, I don't know what the [&] is doing.

Comment: No, you don't need the explicit return type in this case. And the [&] is the capture clause, explained in many lambda introductions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an IntelliSense bug; it has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013.  You can ignore the erroneous error.